# Centering a form?

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm new to foundation and am trying to create a centralized form that has inline labels, I've looked at the example:

```
<form>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="small-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-3 columns">
          <label for="right-label" class="right inline">Label</label>
        </div>
        <div class="small-9 columns">
          <input type="text" id="right-label" placeholder="Inline Text Input">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

How would I go about centering the form on the page? I know you can add...

```
small-centered
```

...to a div, Ive tried this on:

```
<div class="small-8 small-centered">
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `text-align:center;` to .row in which you wanna center things. it really helps.
thanks.